# linear gradient transition not working in CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a transition to an image but it's not working.
here is the code.

```
 .img-4:link,
 .img-4:visited{

  background-image : linear-gradient(#blah,#blah),url(blah);
  transition : background 0.3s linear;
  }

 .img-4:hover,
 .img-4:active{

  background-image : url(blah);
  }
```

Comment: `background-image` is not one of the animatable properties, so you can't use transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [keyframes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) to create animation on something else than `background-image`, because this is not working. The properties you can use may be limited, depending on what kind of animation you want.